# Why am I getting cannot return null for non-nullable field Task.id?

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql, nestjs, prisma

I'm attempting to hit a graphQL server running on my machine with the query

```
query Tasks($where: TaskWhereInput!) {
    tasks(where: $where) {
        id
        title
        userId
    }
}
```

and the variables

```
{
    "where": {
        "userId": {
            "equals": "a16939a5-bd64-456f-afb3-dc7937059f9d"
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason, it responds with `Cannot return null for non-nullable field Task.id.`

The graphQL resolver function is

```
  @Query(() => Task)
  async tasks(@Args() findManyTaskArgs: FindManyTaskArgs): Promise<Task[]> {
    return this.taskService.findMany(findManyTaskArgs.where);
  }
```

and my service action is

```
async findMany(where: Prisma.TaskWhereInput): Promise<Task[]> {
    return this.prisma.task.findMany({
      where,
    });
  }
```

I have no idea why I'm getting this issue, as every other call works fine.
Thank you in advance.

I've tried different types, and switching around the way I called the function. The weird thing is, everything else works.

Comment: Looks like `findMany` returns objects without an `.id` property

Comment: Please include sample output from `this.taskService.findMany(findManyTaskArgs.where)`